# Ошибка парсера XML при встрече с символом &

Tags: php, xml, парсер

Пытаюсь парсить xml-ку (XML-вариант страницы каталога) следующим образом:

```
$xml_string = file_get_contents($URL);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
```

функция **simplexml_load_string()** выдала ошибку после того как на одной из страниц в названии картинки попался символ **&**  (напр. blabla&blabla.png). Как это обойти? Не хочется переписывать весь парсер. =(

Answer (score 1):

Символ `&` в XML используется для представления особых сущностей вида `&amp;`. Каждая такая сущность представляет управляющий символ разметки (`<`, `>`, `"` и т.д.) или некоторые общеупотребимые спец. символы (например ©).

В вашем случае, конструкция `blabla&blabla.png` *не является валидной* в терминах XML. Вместо нее должно использоваться `blabla&amp;blabla.png`.

Хотите использовать стандартные средства по разбору XML - подавайте на вход валидный XML.

Comment: т.е. т.к. на формирование этого XML я повлиять никак не могу (его отдаёт сторонний сайт к которому я не имею никакого отношения и доступов), обходиться кастылями или писать в тех.поддержку сайта? =)

Comment: @maler1988, я бы на писал в техподдержку, предварительно прогнав результат выдачи через XML валидатор (чтобы убедиться в наличии проблемы). В качестве костыля, я бы попробовал регуляркой заменять символы `&` не относящиеся к сущностям на `&amp;`.